# PHP - Como pegar informações do user atraves do $_GET

Tags: php, sql

Ola, tenho uma leaderboard na qual quero fazer com que quando clico em cima do nick do jogador abra o profile contendo as informações dele, porem, não sei exatamente como começar.

Estou tentando:

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) 
{
    $query = $_GET['name'];
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);        
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $query);

    $raw_results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `user` JOIN `statistic` ON `user`.`uuid` = `statistic`.`uuid` LIKE '%". $query ."%'");
    $raw_resultsmedia = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `user` JOIN `social media` ON `user`.`uuid` = `social media`.`uuid` LIKE '%". $query ."%'");

    while($resultsmedia = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_resultsmedia) && $asd = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results))
    {

    }
}
```

o $query pega o nick certinho, porem, na hora de pegar as infos pega errado. ele ja passa por um parametro ?name=Username, mas na hora de pegar as informacoes daquele determinado nick, ele não responde corretamente.

Comment: O *uuid* é um conjunto numérico, logo o parâmetro `name` deverá ser o mesmo conjunto. P.S.: Se você quer pegar os dados de um usuário, não faz sentido usar `LIKE`. P.S².: Você pode usar múltiplos `JOIN` numa *query*.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa noite

O tipo de parâmetro GET é passado para o servidor através da URL, portanto, deve ser estar presente no link, caso o contrário ele mostrará que tal parâmetro não existe. No link que você usa para redirecionar o usuário, adicione o parâmetro name (que é o que você faz referência no código) na URL. Exemplo:

```
<a href="profile.php?name=USERNAME">meu perfil</a>
```

Outras duas coisas me chamaram a atenção, primeiro, evite o uso de espaçadores no nome de suas tabelas, bancos de dados e até mesmo arquivos, e outra, a biblioteca de conexão com o MySQL do PHP já é ultrapassada, tente substituir pela PHP_PDO, que é uma mais recente. Também recomendo que sempre teste suas queries diretamente no banco e sem o uso de variáveis, para que não haja nenhum erro de escrita ou coisa do tipo, mais tarde no código, é só adicionar as variáveis.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Comment: Ola Lucas Deano, ele ja passa por um parametro ?name=Username, mas na hora de pegar as informacoes daquele determinado nick, ele não responde corretamente.

Comment: Olá, de uma olhada nas alterações que eu fiz! Espero ter ajudado!